# Compare two files & output differences (including Line Number and content) from both files

Tags: file, awk, compare

I am attempting to get the differences of both files, line number and content either in another file or stdout. I have attempted the below, yet, not able to get the exact desired output. Please see below.

**File contents:**

File1:

```
Col1,Col2,Col3
Text1,text1,text1
Text2,text2,Rubbish
```

File2:

```
Col1,Col2,Col3
Text1,text1,text1
Text2,text2,text2
Text3,text3,text3
```

I have tried the following code which does not provide the exact desired output as it only shows the difference in the first file and not the extra line in file2.

```
sort file1 file2 | uniq | awk 'FNR==NR{ a[$1]; next } !($1 in a) {print FNR": "$0}' file2 file1
```

Output

```
3: Text2,text2,Rubbish
```

Desired Output

```
3: Text2,text2,Rubbish (File1)
3: Text2,text2,text2 (File2)
4: Text3,text3,text3 (File2)
```

I DONOT wish to use diff/sdiff/comm because of the outputs, as I cannot add line number and organise the data side by side for ease of reading. Normal files would be in excess of 1000 lines so diff/sdiff utilities become more difficult to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
BEGIN { OFS=": " }
FNR==1{ next     }
FNR==NR{
  arr[$0]=FNR
  next
}
!($0 in arr){
  print FNR,$0" ("FILENAME")"
  next
}
{
  arr1[$0]
}
END{
  for(key in arr){
    if(!(key in arr1)){
      print arr[key],key" ("ARGV[1]")"
    }
  }
}
' file1 file2
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                   ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN { OFS=": " }                      ##Setting OFS to colon space in BEGIN section of this program.
FNR==1{ next     }                      ##Skipping if there is FNR==1 for both the files.
FNR==NR{                                ##Checking condition if FNR==NR then do following.
  arr[$0]=FNR                           ##Creating arr with index of current line has FNR as value.
  next                                  ##Will skip all further statements from here.
}
!($0 in arr){                           ##If current line is NOT in arr(to get lines which are in file2 but not in file1)
  print FNR,$0" ("FILENAME")"           ##Printing as per OP request number with file name, line.
  next                                  ##Will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  arr1[$0]                              ##Creating arr1 which has index as current line in it.
}
END{                                    ##Starting END section of this program from here.
  for(key in arr){                      ##Traversing through arr here.
    if(!(key in arr1)){                 ##If key is NOT present in arr1.
      print arr[key],key" ("ARGV[1]")"   ##Printing values of arr and first file name, basically getting lines which are present in file1 and NOT in file2.
    }
  }
}
' file1 file2                           ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Comment: many thanks for the help and detailed explanation. I liked both solutions so was very difficult in choosing - but as yours was extremely detailed, clear and only used awk - I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can get your desired output using GNU diff + awk:

```
funkydiff(){
   # configure diff to output:
   #    - 1 or 2 as flag character to identify file
   #    - space
   #    - line number formatted as integer
   #    - colon, space
   #    - the line content including terminating newline
   diff -d \
       --old-line-format='1 %dn: %L' \
       --new-line-format='2 %dn: %L' \
       --unchanged-line-format='' \
       -- "$1" "$2" \
   | awk '
      # p starts off null
      # initialise filename lookup table
      !p { f[1]=a; f[2]=b }

      {
         # discard first 2 characters of input line
         # append bracketed filename if flag character changed
         # print the result
         print substr($0,3) ($1!=p?" ("f[$1]")":"")

         # update p ready for next line
         p=$1
      }
   ' a="$1" b="$2"
}

funkydiff File1 File2
```

GNU `diff` does most of the hard work.

`awk` checks (and deletes) the filename identifier prefix that diff adds at the start of each line and appends the appropriate filename in brackets where necessary.

---

With your amended (simpler) requirement to print the filenames on every line and not just the first of each group, the awk can be simplified:

```
funkydiff2(){
   diff -d \
      --old-line-format='1 %dn: %L' \
      --new-line-format='2 %dn: %L' \
      --unchanged-line-format='' \
      -- "$1" "$2" \
   | awk '
      !p { f[1]=a; f[2]=b }

      # always append bracketed filename
      # update p as a side-effect (just for brevity)
      { print substr($0,3) " (" f[p=$1] ")" }
   ' a="$1" b="$2"
}
```

---

In fact, awk is not required at all if the filenames don't contain the special `%` character:

```
funkydiff3(){
    case "$1$2" in
        *%*)
            echo 1>&2 "ERROR: funky filename. Aborting"
            return 1
            ;;
    esac

    # now $1 and $2 cannot contain the % metacharacter
    # %c'\012' produces newline
    # alternatively you could embed literal newlines
    diff -d \
        --old-line-format="%dn: %l ($1)%c'\012'" \
        --new-line-format="%dn: %l ($2)%c'\012'" \
        --unchanged-line-format="" \
        -- "$1" "$2"
}
```

Because the filenames become embedded directly in the format strings passed to `diff`, if they contained any `%` the format string would either change to something unintended, become malformed, or cause the filenames to be mangled on output.

The man-page for GNU diff contains details of the `%` sequences that it allows in format strings.

Comment: thank you - I modified the desired output as I missed adding filename for line3 of file2. Would you be able to break down your awk code a bit further please? I removed the awk part and got a similar output. New to awk but trying to use it more. ```1 3: Text2,text2,Rubbish
2 3: Text2,text2,text2
2 4: Text3,text3,text3
```

Comment: I am extremely grateful for the help you provided. I didnt know diff was that powerful and could do what I needed without awk. https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Line-Formats.html using this site to learn more about line formatting. Thank you once again for the support. I can confirm your solution also works.